# No module named 'sklearn.base'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I'm getting an error the following error running the following:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.base'
```

I already have sklearn package imported
`import sklearn` works fine.

Comment: If ````import sklearn```` works, have you tried importing the module and using ````base.BaseEstimator```` instead ````BaseEstimator````. Does this work?

Comment: Any chance your script is named `sklearn.py`? In that case you can import the script (not the module) with `import sklearn` but you cannot do `import sklearn.base` because the script doesn't have submodules or subpackages.

Comment: @Redox doesn't work. gives an error

Comment: @phd I'm working in a Jupiter notebook